# Passing dropdown value to session without refreshing the page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, session-variables

I need to pass select value to a session **without refresh the page**. 
I think onchange event can be used.

Actually, I can put select value into text field.

**HTML**

Select:

```
<select id="dropdown1" class="select" tabindex="2" onchange="run(this)">
    <option>Select</option>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

TextBox:

```
<input type="text" id="car" name="car" id="car" value="<?=$_POST[car]?>" disabled />
```

**JavaScript**

```
function run(sel) {
    var i = sel.selectedIndex;
    if (i != -1) {
        document.getElementById("car").value = sel.options[i].text;
    }
}
```

**Question**

How to set value on a variable when select value from dropdown?

```
$_SESSION['car'] = DROPDOWN VALUE
```

Comment: your onchange event is javascript (client side) and your session variable is php (server side). so if you really need to not refresh the page to set your variable session, you must use ajax request in your onchange event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you can use jQuery, this will work:

```
function run(sel) {

    var i = sel.selectedIndex;
    if (i != -1) {
        document.getElementById("car").value = sel.options[i].text;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "urPHPPage.php",
            data: { car: sel.options[i].text}
        }).done(function( msg ) {});
    }
}
```

and in your PHP file

```
if(isset($_POST["car"])){
   $_SESSION['car'] = $_POST["car"]; //offcourse you will have to do some sanitization here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your session is a server-side event and your `onchange` event is a client-side event, you'll need to use `AJAX` in order to change your dropdown options without refreshing the page.

You will need to run a JavaScript function on `onchange` event.

In that function you need to use `AJAX` in order to connect to your browser/database and save the `session['car']`

Hope it helps.